# SASS variable name getting rendered out instead of hex color

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

Setup is a React app with Material-ui

And my SASS variable names aren't working:

[image]

Here the actual variable name is trying to render?

```
.login-hero {
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: $cyan700;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

---

```
// Material UI colors
$cyan700: #0097A7;
$gray100: #F5F5F5;
$gray800: #424242;

// Elements
$body: #fff;
```

---

package.json

```
"material-ui": "^0.19.2",
"react": "^15.5.4",
"node-sass": "^4.5.3",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"style-loader": "^0.18.2",
"webpack": "1.13.2",
```

### Base object inside of webpack

```
const base = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css|\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Anything else you need to see? Or anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: You are not using `sass-loader` in your webpack config.

Comment: @Prakashsharma thanks I was missing that, however I added it and now running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351745/error-extract-text-webpack-plugin-loader-is-used-without-the-corresponding-pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was importing my _components.scss before my _base which contained the colors and sass mixin

```
/* Vendors */
@import "./vendors/normalize.scss";
@import "./vendors/reset.scss";

/* Modules */
@import "./modules/_base.scss";
@import "./modules/_inputs.scss";
@import "./modules/_buttons.scss";
@import "./modules/_svg.scss";
@import "./modules/_queries.scss";
@import "./modules/defaults.scss";

/* Components */
@import "./modules/_components.scss";
```

Also updated and corrected my config to webpack 3